# Why does jsp files inside webapp folder works, but placed under WEB-INF or any folder under WEB-INF doesn't?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring Web MVC Maven Project. Following is my Project Structure:-

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ3w5.jpg)

The server used is TomCat.

Following is my mvc-config.xml file:-

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

Comment: can you show us the content of the file mvc-config.xml

Comment: Are you trying to go via controller?

Comment: @minion No, I am running it directly. Even in the default example of a new project, same problem is being faced.